# Right way to share object between different users of web application

Tags: java, web-applications, data-sharing

I need to maintain a list of objects in a web application. This list can be viewed or modified (items added or deleted) by any user of the web application. There are chances that many users are accessing (modifying) the list almost at the same time. Which is the right approach to share the list. I can think of 2 ways.

1. Static variable
2. ServletContext

Please let me know which one is right and why. Also, please let me know if there is any other better way.

**EDIT** Issue is sharing objects between different users of application.

Comment: A database. That's what databases are for. And they will handle ACIDity for you. Anything you maintain in memory won't be accessible by another application instance running on another server.

Comment: @JB Nizet : Many people accessing at the same time will put additional load on DB. There are other modules working with DB. So traffic will be high.

Comment: If you are using Jboss you could try a form of in-memory clustered cache

Below link has more info http://docs.jboss.org/jbosscache/1.4.0/TreeCache/en/html/replication.html

Comment: @artfullyContrived : Looking for handling within application itself.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You seem to want to share data among several application instances, thus running in separate JVMs, but at the same time only want an in-memory solution within the application itself. Those two requirements are contradictory.

Comment: @JB Nizet: By application instances, I mean, different users. Edited question. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use database, custom datasource (simple list wrapped by DataSource interface) and many more, but...

> any instance of the web application

should it be `any user of webapp`, right?

Comment: Many people accessing at the same time will put additional load on DB. There are other modules working with DB. So traffic will be high.

Comment: NoSQL DB or in memory db like h2)?

Comment: Looking for handling within application itself.

Comment: ConcurentMap from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html should be good.

Comment: You mean I must use `public static ConcurrentMap<String, MyObject> mySharedMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyObject>(0);` and then use `mySharedMap.putIfAbsent` without worrying ?

Comment: yes, but remember that MyObject implement equals and hashCode methods.

Answer (score 1):

Database if speed is not the most important factor. 
If you need speed some shared memory solution with locking is good. Such as Hazelcast http://www.hazelcast.com/